# I'm using href to call videos from a play list how do I play the video in the same window

Tags: javascript, video

Here is some of the code.
The script below uses an if statement to permit using an image as a link to another page.
Video works perfectly when not in the if statement.
I need the video's to play in the same window not open a new one and I need the image (button) to open a page in a new window.

```
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Promo Video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Promo Video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Promo Video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="../Beyond 2000 About Mike.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 About Mike.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 About Mike.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Slide Show.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Slide Show.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Slide Show.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Hypnosis Facts.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Hypnosis Facts.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 Hypnosis Facts.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 What People Are Saying.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 What People Are Saying.webm" type="video/webm"/>
<source src="../Beyond 2000 What People Are Saying.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
```

```
<h1>Videos</h1>

 <a href="../Beyond 2000 Promo Video.mp4"><img src="Icons/Blue Button.png" alt="Beyond 2000 Entertainment Promo Video"><p class="playlist_btn_text">Promo Video</p></a>

 <a href="../Beyond 2000 About Mike.mp4"><img src="Icons/Purple Button.png" alt="Beyond 2000 Entertainment About Mike Video"><p class="playlist_btn_text">About Mike</p></a>

 <a href="../Beyond 2000 Slide Show.mp4"><img src="Icons/Black Button.png" alt="Beyond 2000 Entertainment Slide Show"/><p class="playlist_btn_text">Slide Show</p></a>

 <a href="../Beyond 2000 Hypnosis Facts.mp4"><img src="Icons/Yellow Button.png" alt="Beyond 2000 Entertainment Hypnosis Facts Video"><p class="playlist_btn_text">Hypnosis Facts</p></a>

 <a href="../Beyond 2000 What People Are Saying.mp4"><img src="Icons/Orange Button.png" alt="Beyond 2000 Entertainment What People Are Saying Video"/><p class="playlist_btn_text"> People Saying</p></a>
```

```
if(href="../The Beyond Advantage/The Beyond Advantage.html"){

}
else{       

    var video_playlist = document.getElementById("video_player");
         var links = video_playlist.getElementsByTagName('a');
         for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            links[i].onclick = handler;
         };

         function handler(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            videotarget = this.getAttribute("href");
            filename = videotarget.substr(0, videotarget.lastIndexOf('.')) || videotarget;
            video = document.querySelector("#video_player video");
            video.removeAttribute("poster");
            source = document.querySelectorAll("#video_player video source");
            source[0].src = filename + ".mp4";
            source[1].src = filename + ".webm";
            source[2].src = filename + ".ogv";
            this.video.load();  
            video.play();               
        };
```

Comment: Either don't use `a href`, or put this `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` after your `e.preventDefault`

Comment: `stopImmediatePropagation` seems to be a jQuery thing. It does `stopPropagation` and blocks other event listeners. Do not use this.

Comment: @Halcyon - [**w3c**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopImmediatePropagation) doesn't seem to mention anything about that

Comment: Ah I see, it is part of the w3c spec. That doesn't change my recommendation. It seems like a terrible idea to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already looks like it will load the video in the player. But since your links have `href` on them (which is good!) the default action is to load that page. The usual fix is to `event.preventDefault()`

I'm not sure how you're adding the onclick events but if you're using `addEventListener` do:

```
elem.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    load_video(elem.href);
});
```

Comment: If I remove the if else statement video works perfectly and opens in the same window in the video player.

Comment: If I remove the if else statement video works perfectly and opens in the same window in the video player. However if I select the advantage image(button) it starts the first video. it should send you to the advantage page. using the if else the advantage image  (button) works and takes you to a new page. but then the video opens in a new window. What I require is for the advantage image when clicked on to take me to the advantage page along with when a video is selected it plays in the same window in the video player. So far I have only been able to have one or the other.

Comment: Just found the answer and I feel silly. The dang advantage page image (button) was in the video div. The video div was actually at the bottom of the page not sure why. Everything works perfectly now. Looking for great video player with a selectable play list help your self to the above code